# Studying the Siddur before Yomim Noraim?

Tags: tefilla, prayer-book, yom-kippur

The [Shulchan Aruch OC (100:1)](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.100.1?lang=bi&p2=Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.100.1&lang2=bi) writes that there is an obligation to learn the tefillos which are not commonly said beforehand, and the Rema notes that nowadays we don't need to review the prayers because we have a Siddur. However, the [Mishna Berura (100:3)](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.100.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) adds:

מתוך הסידור - ותפילות ופיוטים שחמור פירושם צריך להסדיר תחלה ולא מהני ספר בזה - The tefillos and piyutim are more stringent and must be reviewed beforehand since a Siddur doesn't help with this.

Seemingly, the Chofetz Chaim would require us to review the entire Rosh Hashana/Yom Kippur Machzor *before* the Yomim Noraim. Is this something everyone does that I'm just not aware of or is there a heter we rely on today not to spend a while reviewing those tefillos beforehand?

Answer (score 1):

I think "are more stringent" is a mistranslation of שחמור פירושם. An accurate translation of ותפילות ופיוטים שחמור פירושם would be "tefillos and piyutim whose explanations are difficult", meaning that they are hard to understand. So one should review difficult sections of the prayers. Presumably the definition of difficult varies from person to person. In addition, over the years you should become more and more familiar.

So one should review portions of the prayers they are not familiar with. Personally I try to review the piyutim from selichos the day before, as they use very poetic language and unusual words.

See the Shaarei Teshuva referenced by the Mishna Berura that memorable tefillos such as Al HaNissim do not need to be prepared, and a discussion of the prayers of Moadim.

So if I know someone does not prepare, I would be dan l'kaf zechus that they think they are familiar with all the piyutim already for previous years. Or they just are not familiar with this halacha.

Comment: Thank you for your fair point regarding my mistranslation - I meant to provide context that the Mishna Berura is being strict beyond the Rema's heter of using a Siddur. Your answer to my question seems to be, "Yes, people are supposed to review all the Piyutim of the Yomim Noraim beforehand. I'm not aware of a heter." Is that accurate?

Comment: @NJM No piyutim are strictly required to be said at all so they can't be required to be studied. To the extent that one wants to have a meaningful and productive experience saying them (highly recommended), preparing them is rather prudent.

Comment: @NJM The heter would be if you are already familiar with the piyutim. It is important to note that the MB is just quoting the Taz here. The basic halacha is, "If you are going to say something, you better make sure you can say it correctly and know what you are saying." If you will say it by heart, make sure you know it by heart. If you have a siddur,  make sure you understand it in advance.

Comment: @DoubleAA It is true you don't have to say it, but if you do, you should understand it. Saying something you don't understand is worse than not saying it at all.

Comment: @N.T. Source? Why isn't it at most equivalent to not saying it all? (And anyway that's a false dichotomy generally speaking. Better to say something with half understanding than to say nothing at all.)

Comment: Worth noting as well @NJM that this entire rule is somewhat of a chiddush. The rule in shulchan aruch to review the prayers says it's in order that the prayers be שגורה בפיו that they should flow from your mouth. Arguably the goal is to speak clearly when standing before God and not stammer or lose track of your place in the prayer whether or not you understand it, and that is why using a siddur works. Piyyutim would be no different. Additionally, it's not obvious this applies to the tzibbur and not just the chazzan for whom the piyyutim are part of his actual tefilla.

Comment: @DoubleAA The source is https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.29.13?lang=bi&with=Chomat%20Anakh&lang2=he   The proof is that the Taz et al. clearly say one must prepare piyutim, so your reasoning must be flawed.

Comment: @N.T. Way to quote something out of context. Trying to pray meaningfully and not understanding the words is not the same as not caring to pray meaningfully.

Comment: "is there a heter we rely on today not to spend a while reviewing those tefillos beforehand" is the question. You have a svara but I have many other svaros and minhag yisrael on my side.

Comment: @DoubleAA It looks like you removed my comment that it isn't really trying if you have an obligation to prepare in advance (from the gemara in Rosh Hashana and brought in all poskim) and you don't.

Comment: You're joking right? The Rama says ואני לא ראיתי בזמן הזה לנהוג לסדר התפלה תחלה ולכן נראה שסמכו על דברי הר"ר מנוח דמסתבר הוא do you think back then everyone understood all the piyyutim straight without preparing? Remember they said 10 times the number of piyyutim that you probably say. Clearly the Rama thought using a siddur is sufficient. The Shaarei Teshuva can argue on him (I'm not convinced he does) but your selective presentation of the halachic literature on the topic is beyond disingenuous.

Comment: The Rema is commenting on the Beis Yosef who says not to rely on Rabbeinu Manoach. He says the minhag is to rely on Rabbeinu Manoach. However, the Taz and Shiurei Knesses HaGedolah quoted in Mishna Berurah clearly understand the Rema to not be referring to Tefillos that are unusually difficult, just the Tefillos of Moadim etc. that are better known. The Kaf Hachayim makes the same point.

Comment: That's all fine and dandy but the fact remains the Rama didn't see anyone doing this and thought he was justifying their practice. The Taz is not the only valid interpretation here. I'm not debating that the Taz says what he says. I'm just criticizing you for ignoring the rest of Judaism.

Comment: Your criticism equally applies to your understanding of the Taz et al., so I'm in good company. However, the Taz and every source I have seen is clearly explaining what the Rema meant, not arguing on him. It is basically your interpretation of the Rema vs. actual poskim. Again, the Shiurei Knesses Hagedolah also makes the point that many don't prepare the tefillos, and says they are wrong to do so. In addition, I think it is not true to say nobody prepares the tefillos in advance. There are many books and shiurim on the tefillos of Yamim Noraim and other days, and people study them. I do.

Comment: No, my criticism does not apply equally to the Taz because he is not expected to provide a balanced perspective on a website. He can provide his own (mechuddash) opinions as he saw fit to do here. You though should do better than this.

Comment: I didn't know websites had higher standards than meforshim in Shulchan Aruch. I also didn't know being balanced meant going, "Hmm, Taz, Baer Heiteiv, Shaarei Teshuva, Mishnah Berurah, Kaf Hachayim on one side, and @DoubleAA on the other side. Better make sure no one feels left out."

Comment: I'm done being misinterpreted. Go review my comments before the next holiday.